# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, list

I want to create a funcion that print the most appeared number, but I have the problem on the title, this is my function:

```
def most_appear_q3(word):
    most = 0
    for num in word:
        num_checked= num
        if(word.count(num)>= most):
            most = word.count(num)
        else:
            del word[num_checked]
        print [most + word]

most_appear_q3([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6])
```

This is the error:

```
print [most + word]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

the result need to be 3,[2,5] because 2 and 5 appear 3 times

Comment: You can not add `int` to a `list`...I think it should be `print (most, word)` .. is that what you want?...only printing?

Comment: Also, don't delete elements from a list while iterating over it.

Comment: `most` is an `int`. `word` is a `list`. You can't add them together with `+`.

Comment: Also, your algorithm isn't doing anything close to what you probably wanted it to. From deleting elements as you iterate (as timgeb) said to confusing an element with its index, the error message you ended up with is just the first in line.

Comment: @ariel20 check my answer

Comment: @ariel20 ... after your edit and if you say that `word` must be a dictionay, then why did you show in your example a list of numbers instead?...Can you edit your question to elaborate more what you want precisely?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to delete items from your list in order to filter at the end the item with most occurrence in your list, simply, just iterate through it and keep the value with maximum count in your variable and store elements with that max count in a list then return max count and list, this way:

```
def most_appear_q3(word):
    most = 0
    most_comm = []
    for num in word:
        #num_checked= num - No need for this line
        c = word.count(num) 
        if(c == most) and num not in most_comm: #To avoid Duplicate items
            most_comm.append(num)# Found an element with same max counting
        elif (c > most):
            most = c #New Max Count Found
            most_comm = [] #delete all previous elements
            most_comm.append(num)
    return most, most_comm

>>>print most_appear_q3([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6]) #or print (most_appear_q3([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6])) if you are using Python 3+
(3, [2, 5])
```

An alternative way, is to use built in method, like `max` with `key` being the `count` of each item, this way:

```
>>> l = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6]
>>> max(l, key=lambda s:l.count(s))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have done some minor mistakes like:
    1. It will not check the first number.
    2. Print should be out side the loop
    3. you have already mentioned.

To fix the error mentioned by you, you have need to change 
the print statement. 
def most_appear_q3(word):
    most = 0
    for num in word:
        num_checked= num
        if(word.count(num)>= most):
            most = word.count(num)
        else:
            del word[num_checked]
        print (str(most) + str(word))

most_appear_q3([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6])
Result:
>>> 
1[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6]
3[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]
>>> 

I think this is not what you expected, so modifying the code. 
May be this will help you.

def filter_least_appeared(word, count, num):
    if(word.count(num)>= count):
        count = word.count(num)
    else:
        word[:] = filter(lambda val: val != num, word)
    return word, count

def most_appear_q3(word):
    count = 0
    """ This will not check the first number."""
    for num in set(word):
        word, count = filter_least_appeared(word, count, num)

    """Check for first number."""
    word, count = filter_least_appeared(word, count, list(set(word))[0])

    print (str(count) + ',' + str(list(set(word))))

most_appear_q3([1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6])

>>> 
3,[2, 5]
>>>
```